# Fragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false); doesn't work (enter and exit animation overlap)

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I'm replacing Fragment with :

```
Fragment fragment = new TheFragment();
fragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.LayoutContent, fragment).commit();
```

But the enter en exit animation are played at the same time.

How can I wait for exit animation to finish before playing the new Fragment enter animation ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is already late but I would like to answer for others having the same issue.

```
fragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
fragment.setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(false);
```

only works for Content Transition - transition set directly at the fragment.

```
enteringfragment.setEnterTransition(new YourTransition())
exitingfragment.setExitTransition(new YourTransition())
```

it does not affect the animation set at the `setCustomAnimations()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit dirty but I solved this problem by just defining the

> android:startOffset

of the enter animation with the same value as the

> android:duration

of the exit animation. Additionally I used the time from a variable to make sure that it is always the same value in both animations and I only have to change it at one place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.
Simply use

```
setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
setAllowExitTransitionOverlap(false);
```

on both fragments and it works.